# how is looks like post request to btc-e

Tags: qt, post

I trying send post-request to btc-e.com ( documentation https://btc-e.com/api/documentation)
There is my code, but

```
QString str;
QDateTime qtime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
qint64 time = qtime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000;
str.setNum(time);
str = "method=getInfo&nonce=" + str;
QByteArray sign = hmacSha512(secret,str);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(url);
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRawHeader("Key", key);
request.setRawHeader("Sign", sign);
post->post(request,str.toUtf8());
```

as the result of this request is error "400 BAD REQUEST", I cannot find any mistakes. Please, help me. May be I send an incorrect request , because example of correct is described nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted all your code so it is hard to help.

To get a http OK - 200 as per screenshot [image: terminal output])

I added a bit of code and built it on Mac with Qt 5.2:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include "myhandler.h"

// Thanks to http://www.askyb.com/cpp/openssl-hmac-hasing-example-in-cpp/
QByteArray hmacSha512(const QString &secret, const QString &str)
{
    unsigned char* digest;
    digest = HMAC(EVP_sha512(), qPrintable(secret), secret.length(), (unsigned char*)qPrintable(str), str.length(), NULL, NULL);

    char mdString[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    printf("HMAC digest: %s\n", mdString);
    return QByteArray(mdString);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyHandler *handler = new MyHandler;

    // The key to hash
    QByteArray key = "46G9R9D6-WJ77XOIP-XH9HH5VQ-A3XN3YOZ-8T1R8I8T";
    QString secret = "12345678";

    QUrl url("https://btc-e.com/tapi");
    QNetworkAccessManager *post = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QObject::connect(post, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                    handler, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    // ----8<----------- YOUR CODE -----------
    QString str;
    QDateTime qtime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    qint64 time = qtime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000;
    str.setNum(time);
    str = "method=getInfo&nonce=" + str;
    QByteArray sign = hmacSha512(secret,str);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRawHeader("Key", key);
    request.setRawHeader("Sign", sign);
    post->post(request,str.toUtf8());
    // ----8<----------- YOUR CODE -----------

    return a.exec();
}
```

and simply a small handler class

```
#ifndef MYHANDLER_H
#define MYHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>

class QNetworkReply;

class MyHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyHandler(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};

#endif // MYHANDLER_H
```

and implementation:

```
#include "myhandler.h"

#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>

MyHandler::MyHandler(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void MyHandler::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    QTextStream ts(reply);
    while (!ts.atEnd())
    {
        qDebug() << ts.readLine();
    }
}
```